# Openlayers restrict zoom to whole world

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using OpenStreetMap with openlayers and I transform 900913 to 27700. I am using maxextent and trying to center the map but what I want to achieve is that the map should not zoom out to the whole world. How can I do that? My code is as below

```
var projDisplay = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:27700");
var projmerc = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

map = new OpenLayers.Map("map",                  {scales[200000,150000,100000,50000,20000,10000,5000,2500],
                                                maxExtent: new   openLayers.Bounds("350000,380000, 380000,400000"),
                                                minzoomlevel: "10",
                                                numZoomLevels: "19",
                                                units: 'm',
                                                projection: projmerc,
                                                displayProjection: projDisplay} );


var mapnik_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap");
map.addLayers([mapnik_layer]);

var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat("362431.71","389042.78");
lonlat.transform(projDisplay, projmerc);
map.setCenter(lonlat, 13);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will confess I have never used Mapnik, so I do not what all it can do, but assuming the typos in your posted code--for example, should be 'scales:[' and not 'scales['--are not in your working code, you must not set any other scale-dependent options (e.g., numZoomLevels, minZoomlevel) in your map options as they will override your scales setting.

But more importantly, the layer settings will override map settings, and in this case, I do not think OpenLayers.Layer.OSM, as a third-party provider, will let you set your own scales. If working with a relatively small area of OSM, why not download the bounding box of your maxExtents and serve the map data yourself for more flexibility?

A few useful links:

http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/SettingZoomLevels

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/openlayers-use-scales-instead-of-resolutions

ADDING:

And here is a fiddle to play with (non-Mapnik) of your map where it is zooming correctly to your max extent and not the whole world, as requested:

http://jsfiddle.net/Cybele42/UfWp9/3/

Javascript:

```
var projMercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("GOOGLE");
var projBritNatGrid = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:27700");

var navigation_control = new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({});

var controls_array = [
    navigation_control,
    new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar({}),
    new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({}),
    new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({})
];

var layerOSM = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap");
var scales = [200000,150000,100000,50000,20000,10000,5000,2500];

var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    units: 'm',
    scales: scales,
    Projection: projMercator,
    DisplayProj: projBritNatGrid,
    controls: controls_array
});

map.addLayer(layerOSM);

var myMaxExtent = new OpenLayers.Bounds("350000,380000, 380000,400000");
myMaxExtent.transform(projBritNatGrid, projMercator);

var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat("362431.71","389042.78");
lonlat.transform(projBritNatGrid, projMercator);
map.setCenter(lonlat, 13);

map.events.register("zoomend", map, function(){
document.getElementById("getCenter").innerHTML=map.getCenter();
document.getElementById("getScale").innerHTML=map.getScale();
});
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/1.1.0/proj4js-compressed.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/27700/proj4js/"></script>

<div id="map"></div>

<table class="gridtable">
<tr><th>object</th><th>value</th></tr>
<tr><td>Center</td><td><div id="getCenter"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td>Scale</td><td><div id="getScale"></div></td></tr>   
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#map
{
   width: 600px;
   height: 600px;
   border: 1px solid black;
}

table.gridtable {
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333333;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table.gridtable th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: khaki;
}

table.gridtable td {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```